# Turn an array into an bidimensional array and remove the first 11 entries

Tags: php

I have been trying to figure this out until my brain imploded.
Im trying to sort an array.

The first 11 entries has to be removed, then the next 7 entries has to be placed in an new array and then the next 7 entries and so on. Until there is no more entries.

Short example:

**Turn this:**

```
Array (
     [0] => 0
     [1] => 1
     [2] => 2
     [3] => 3
     [4] => 4
     [5] => 5
     [6] => 6
     [7] => 7
     [8] => 8
     [9] => 9
     [10] => 10
     [11] => 11
     [12] => 12
     [13] => 13
     [14] => 14
     [15] => 15
     [16] => 16
     [17] => 17
     [18] => 18
)
```

**Into this:**

```
Array (
     [0] => Array (
               [0] => 11
               [1] => 12
               [2] => 13
               [3] => 14
               [4] => 15
               [5] => 16
               [6] => 17
            )
)
```

Comment: As shown by hakre's answer, this is a combination of two basic tasks/questions.  How to remove the first N elements in an array? And How to split an array into chunks of not more than N elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$orig = array(...);

$i = 11; // start at offset 11
$remove = 7; // take off 7 at a time

$new = array();
while($i <= count($orig)) {
   $new[] = array_slice($orig, $i, $remove);
   $i += $remove;
}
```

$new will have your new multi-dimensionalized array

Answer (score 1):

Why do a `while` when you can do a `for`

```
$a = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20); // your array

$ret = array(); // new array

for($i=11; $i < sizeof($a); $i+=7)
  $ret[] = array_slice($a, $i, 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice) to get a part and [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/array_chunk) to chunk the leftover:

```
// take out the first 11 elements
$array = array_slice($array, 11);

// create chunks with 7 entries each
$array = array_chunk($array, 7);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AEVnir)